# What is wrong with my Quicksort for the following array?

Tags: c#, quicksort

I'm writing a Quicksort algorithm without checking existing code out there and I came up with the following code:

```
public class QuicksortV7
{
    public void QuickSort(int[] arr, int start, int end)
    {
        int pivot = start;
        int left = start + 1;
        int right = end;

        while (left < right)
        {
            while (arr[left] <= arr[pivot] && left <= right) { left++; }
            while (arr[right] >= arr[pivot] && right >= left) { right--; }
            if (left >= right)
            {
                if (arr[pivot] > arr[right])
                {
                    int aux = arr[pivot];
                    arr[pivot] = arr[right];
                    arr[right] = aux;
                }

                QuickSort(arr, start, right - 1);
                QuickSort(arr, right + 1, end);
            }
            else
            {
                int aux = arr[left];
                arr[left] = arr[right];
                arr[right] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 69, 66, 92, 53, 11, 40, 59, 60, 17, 13, 53, 46, 30 };
        var quick = new QuicksortV7();
        quick.QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
    }
```

It seems this is not good, since a given array example fails:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 69, 66, 92, 53, 11, 40, 59, 60, 17, 13, 53, 46, 30 };
```

The above array after it runs is:

```
11, 13, 30, 17, 40, 46, 53, 53, 59, 66, 60, 69, 92
```

I've been trying to test it on paper instruction by instruction but I can't reach the problem

any tips are welcome thanks

Comment: Debug through it, line by line. On each line, before it executes, come up with a mental model of what you expect that line to do. Then run the line. Did it not do what you expect? If so, either correct your mental model or you have found the bug. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Run it on a shorter array. Run it on a prearranged array, when the sequence has to be reversed, or only two items has to be swapped.

Comment: Ran your code on a couple of arrays, `{ 60, 59, 58}` throws an index out of range exception and `{ 59, 66, 60 }` gives incorrect result. Seems like you are pivoting on the `right` variable but comparing with the `pivot` one. You should have a look at Bob's answer for the correct way of implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your code and found a couple of issues. I noted them in comments below.
I got it working with your example input.

```
public void QuickSort(int[] arr, int start, int end)
{
    int pivot = start;
    int left = start + 1;
    int right = end;

    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (arr[left] < arr[pivot] /*&& left <= right */) { left++; }
        while (arr[right] > arr[pivot] /*&& right >= left*/) { right--; }
        if (left <= right)
        {
            //if (arr[pivot] > arr[right]) // This if is not needed
            //{
                int aux = arr[left]; //Swap left and right, not pivot
                arr[left] = arr[right];
                arr[right] = aux;

                left++;
                right--;
           // }

            // This is done after the sorting loop
            //QuickSort(arr, start, right - 1); 
            //QuickSort(arr, right + 1, end);
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    int aux = arr[left];
        //    arr[left] = arr[right];
        //    arr[right] = aux;
        //}
    }

    // Do recursion after sorting loop is done
    if (start < right)
        QuickSort(arr, start, left);
    if (left < end)
        QuickSort(arr, left, end);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Since the algorithm is a divide-and-conquer technique of sorting. I typically like to split the quicksort algorithm up into two separate methods. The quicksort call method to recursively call it and the partition method to split the elements.

You are basically trying to cram a full recursive sorting algorithm into one method. Would take notes from this example and try it again.

```
public void Quicksort(int[] array, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = 0;
    if(high > low)
    {
        pivot = Partition(array, low, high);
        QuickSort(array, low, pivot - 1);
        QuickSort(array, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}

public static int Partition(int[] array, int low, int high)
{
    int left, right, piviot_item, = A[low];
    left = low;
    right = high;

    while(left < right)
    { 
        // move left while item < piviot
        while (array[left] < array[right])
        {
            left++;
        }

        while(array[right] > pivot_item)
        { 
            // move right while item > piviot
            right--;
        }

        if(left < right)
        {
            // swap the left and right item within the array
            swap(array, left, right)
        }

    }
    // final position of pivot
    array[low] = a[right];
}
```

Comment: While your advice is good, you are not answering why his program does not work. This belongs in just a comment then.